# Using SPD 2010 with later versions

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a windows 7 professional system with Office 13 and SharePoint Designer 2013 and 2010 (yes 2010 works with later version if now maintenance is applied)

HOWEVER
Darn maintenance keeps getting applied to the SharePoint Designer 2010 and I end up uninstalling and reinstalling daily to use it.

Is there anyway to turn maintenance off? 
Also each time I re-install SPD 2010 when I open access 2013 it forces a re-install of that